# I can't get more than one applet communicating with my Cpp server

Tags: java, c++, applet, winsock

For some reason when I connect one Java client to my Cpp server it works perfectly. But when another Java applet tries to connect in addition to the first, it does but it stops receiving data from the server. Some of the other attempts would completly freeze the applet. I have searched everywhere on the 'net but found nothing. I would appreciate any help on the subject like advice, links or source. My only other option (since Flash is out of the question) is to use Active X, but then I would lose all my crossplatform-ability :(.  My source (minus debugging code and so on) follows.

```
public void init() {

    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost",4000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
        return;
    }

    BufferedReader fromServer = null;
    PrintWriter toServer = null;

    fromServer = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    toServer = 
    new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    toServer.flush();
```

Comment: What's happening server side?

Comment: The server seems to be fine.  It's written in Cpp and I can connect just fine using PuTTY

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Cpp server can't handle multiple connections. Can you verify that you can accept more than one incoming network connection?

Comment: Yes.  I used PuTTY and connected using multiple connections

Comment: Alright: to clarify, you can connect multiple putty instances and send data from all of them at the same time and receive responses? I'd suspect that your applet is freezing in a read loop somewhere because it is waiting for data in the event dispatch thread and not receiving it in a timely fashion. Your code above doesn't include enough to figure out where specifically it is freezing, so I'd check that out.

Comment: Yes I can use multiple PuTTY connections and send and receive data from all of them at once.  I could copy all my code here but it's 83 lines long!  If you want a specific part of my malfunctioning program let me know.

Comment: Well, I expect the issue is in the applet, not the server, and that is probably more than 83 lines long. If you can paste the entire methods that communicate with the server and the calling contexts (so where they are called from) that would probably be helpful.

Comment: That's the socket connection code: edit your question to include all methods where you either send data to or read data from the socket, AND the methods that call those methods.

Comment: try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost",4000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Unknown host");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
            return;
        }

   fromServer = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
   toServer = 
    new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    toServer.flush();

         toServer.println(numb);

         try 
  {
              numbStr = fromServer.readLine();
         }

Comment: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) is the method where the sending and receving happen.  It does this in responce to a button press

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! You can't run multiple applets in one browser and one machine.  It will work if you load them in seperate browsers (like IE and FF) or load it on a seperate machine (like remotely).  I hope this helps.